# Cannot format time output

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, datebox

I'm using [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) as a time picker control in my web application, and it works, but I'm having some trouble with formatting the time output.

The documentation on the site is pretty complete... or so it seems. It's as if some of the settings don't work at all.

I've tried using the `timeOutput` option to format the output string, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Does anybody have experience using the DateBox plugin? Could I get some advice on formatting the time output string?

Here's the code I use to set up the TimeBox control:

```
$("input[type=time]").datebox({
    mode: "timebox",
    zindex: 2100,
    useNewStyle: true,
    centerHoriz: true,
    centerVert: true,
    useClearButton: true,
    overrideTimeFormat: 12
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't disagree at all on the documentation.  The problem is, this is a project I work on in my (not copious) free time, and on top of that, I am terrible at writing documentation.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary comment. I'm actually surprised that nobody had removed it before now. Thanks for all your hard work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies partially in my negligence and partially in the documentation's organization.

At the *very* bottom of [this page](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html), there's a section labeled "Internationalization/Localization," where the option I've been trying to use, `timeOutput`, is located.

What I *didn't* notice is that at the top of the list of options, there's a note that reads:

> NOTE:: To override, use overrideNameOfOption - e.g. overrideTimeFormat

So, that said, it turns out that you *do* have to override the `timeOutput` option by setting it as follows:

```
$("input[type=time]").datebox({
    mode: "timebox",
    zindex: 2100,
    useNewStyle: true,
    centerHoriz: true,
    centerVert: true,
    useClearButton: true,
    overrideTimeFormat: 12,
    overrideTimeOutput: "%l:%M %p"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for digging into this, I had the exact same problem.

Another pointer -- **make sure to use** **camelcase** as the author describes [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/doc/3-3-output/), in the "reminder about  overrides."

e.g. -- "overrideTimeOutput" works, but "overrideTimeoutput" doesn't.

I agree, this is a very cool little plugin. I'm perhaps a bit more lenient regarding the documentation -- while it takes some digging to figure things out, I've learned a lot from it (including the pointer above).

I also appreciate the author's presence in these and other forums -- that has helped tremendously too. I wish he/she would make registering on his/her site easier -- I tried about fifteen times, kept getting inexplicable error messages, and gave up.

But that's a quibble. Long live the community!!